# Why this Regex works normally but not inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on this thing for the last 2 hours,  why is the first regex working and not the second?  Why both regexes are working when not inside a for loop?

Thanks!

```js
var urlRegex = /((http|https):\/\/)?((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF_-]+\.)+))?((([a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF_-][0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF_-]?[0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF-_]?)|([a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF_-]{4,1000}))\.(?:([a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]{3,3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF_-]+)))([a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF_.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF@?^=%&~+#-])?/g;
var updatedData = { websiteUrl: 
   [ 'http://www.kdjyufghsuidt.ca/ghsuidt_fr.html',
     'http://dasjhdjha.kl' ] };

var iRegex;

var queryArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i< updatedData.websiteUrl.length; i++) {

queryArray.push(urlRegex.exec(updatedData.websiteUrl[i]));
}

console.log("queryArray at [1] should be a valid array, but instead it's null: " + JSON.stringify(queryArray[1]));

console.log("queryArray at [0] is working normally: " + JSON.stringify(queryArray[0]));
```

Comment: It's because of the `/g`.  That flag effectively tells the regex to keep track of its position.

Comment: @Amy  Ah yeah? I thought I was executing each Regex separately when using `.exec`

Comment: @Emilio try it without the "g" flag.  That changes the behavior of `.exec()` in a very significant way.

Comment: @Emilio you are.  the point is that the flag tells the regex to keep track of its last matched index.  See the dupe.

Comment: @Amy  I'm looking at it now! thanks!